# Logging into multiple tables using NLog

Tags: nlog

I am in search of method or ways to log data into multiple tables using NLog. I have more than one log tables with different structures in my case. And, I would like to log two different datas in these two tables.

Please let me know if there is a way to configure NLog to handle two different tables while logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two database targets, one for each table.

e.g.

```xml
<targets>
  <target name="table1" xsi:type="Database"
         ... />
  <target name="table2" xsi:type="Database"
         ... />
</targets>

<rules>
   <logger name="logger1" minlevel="Info" writeTo="table1" />
   <logger name="logger2" minlevel="Info" writeTo="table2" />
</rules>
```

Comment: while logging can I choose which of these two tables to log to?

Comment: yes, you could create more loggers or more advanced rules, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules